# How to bind data to custom calendar widget

Tags: android, json, calendar

I am doing a project based on getting events from Server and display them in a calendar widget. I am able to display the calendar in my app. but unable to bind the server data into the calendar. i want some thing like this:
[image]

I am getting the Calendar view,but i want to bind the server events and display them like above shown.

[image]

If any event is there, it should visible on the particular date. Suggest me the best way to do this.

Comment: Can u send me this demo app or link? @wolverine

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally run a background task that downloads everything into a database and is then displays them in the listview after an on click event.